# Multiple INSERT INTO MySQL from $_POST array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, insert

I am receiving the following arrays from a form:

```
array (size=1)
    'checkbox' => 
array (size=2)
    0 => string '14' (length=2)
    1 => string '13' (length=2)
    2 => string '15' (length=2)
array (size=1)
    'id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I need to build a query looking like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(column1,column2) VALUES (14,1),(13,1),(15,1)";
```

And the first array will be different every time based on the checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can try looping with a foreach on that array. So let's say you have named your checkboxes as `name="checkbox[]"`.

Then on the page where you are processing the `$_POST` vars you can do

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(column1,column2) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $box) {
    //process each checkbox here
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $box, $otherValue);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

This is just a pseudo-code to get you started.

You can find more info on prepared statements here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create an empty array to store each checkbox value
$values = array();

if(is_array($_POST['checkbox'])){
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox){
        foreach($checkbox as $key => $value){

            // add each checkbox value to an array
            $values[] = ($value,$_POST['id']);

        }
    }
}

// if the array has values..
if(count($values)){

    // implode the values into a string..
    $sqlValues = implode(',',$values);

    // ..and use that string in the query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table(column1,column2) VALUES $sqlValues";

}
```

Comment: This code is broken. It looks like you tried to use tuples in PHP and PHP doesn't have tuples. Besides this is not how you use prepared statements. The SQL would still be broken if you did it this way.